# Triac snubber: Where to put current limiting phototriac resistor?

Tags: triac, snubber

I have seen two variants for putting the current limiting resistor of the phototriac. One is to put it between R and C of the snubber circuit, the other one is to connect it to the triac terminal directly.

What is the difference between the two? Does the second circuit also protect the phototriac from voltage spikes (too high dV/dt)? Is one of those circuits better?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the simulation models, viewed from a distance, I would say at first that there is no difference.
[image: triac1]

[image: triac2]

A small thing appears because in the second case, the currents of the optocoupler became smaller.

Magnified, the difference is already visible.

[image: triac19]

[image: triac25]

In the first case, the current duration of the optocoupler is longer, the value of the current is higher. This is natural, because if we take a closer look, the optocoupler should discharge most of the capacitor 22n. The optocoupler thus conduct longer than the time required to turn on the triac. This is almost the time constant of C1 R2. So as usual we can choose between two bad ones. In the first case, the optocoupler will be protected against dV / dt peaks, but will heat up more strongly.
In the second case, the optocoupler average current will be much lower and its protection will be provided by a snubber located in the main circuit of the triac.
This is a little less protection. I would choose the second one (based on practice only, I can’t prove it’s better, it just used to be good).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If simplify everything:

1. First schematic limits dV/dt mostly for optocoupler, and may use smaller components.
2. Second schematic limits dV/dt for both opocoupler and power triac. But it depends on load inductance and requires more massive RC.

If you use 3Q snubberless triac, first schematic will be enough. To calclate values - read [Panasonic Application Note 030, Driving Triacs with Phototriacs](https://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/cps/rde/xbcr/pew_eu_en/dd_x615_en_an_030.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd has some proportional R ratio gain so it can respond slightly faster on bright input but 1st can ignore flashes of light controlled current with R1C=T  LPF.

Neither affect Triac more if R2C are the same.
generally R1>>R2 for delay.

Comment: My apologizes, but I do not understand anything. What is proportional R ratio gain, bright input, flashes of light controlled current, and T LPF?

Comment: You have to analyze each transfer impedance vs f

Comment: @Tony, you still need to write the TSLoA (Tony Steward List of Acronyms) and link it in your user profile. :^)